# Nested table not full height in <td> cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am nesting a `table` within a `td`. In Firefox the nested table fills the entire td cell top to bottom but in Edge and Chrome the nested table is centered within the `td` cell not filling the cell. I will eventually have this table span multiple rows and would like the black bar that is created span the multiple rows.

This is the way I'd like it to look (Firefox)
[notice that the black band goes top to bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enjLi.jpg)

This is how it appears in Edge and Chrome
[note that the nested table does NOT fill the entire cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0VaJ.jpg)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="font: 8pt Verdana; width:100%;">
  <tr style="background-color:#ffcc00;color:black;">
    <th style="width:170px">
      <table style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font: 8pt verdana; vertical-align: 100%; 
                        height: 100%; width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="width:40%; margin:0px; text-align: left;">
            <strong>Mile<br />Marker</strong></td>
          <td style="width:1%;margin: 0px auto;">&nbsp;<br /></td>
          <td style="width:59%;margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;">
            <strong>The Safety<br />Rating</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Directions</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Comments</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Number of Vehicles</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="padding: 9px; color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; 
                    font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;width:70px;">
      <strong>&nbsp;Map&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><br />
      <strong>&nbsp;Weather&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><br />
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Source</strong>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="firstRow" style="background-color:#ffff99; font: 8pt verdana;height:100%">
    <!-- There will be multiple table rows added here - I just simplified the code to find out where 
                      my probem originated from -->
    <td style='height: 100%; text-align:center;' rowspan='1'>
      <!--ok to here-->

      <!--In Edge and Chrome the nested table doesn't fill the entire <td> cell top to bottom - 
         Firefox works the way I would like it to -->
      <table id="This is where my problem resides" style='padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 100%; 
                        border:thin solid #800080; background-color:#ffff99;'>
        <tr style=' font: 8pt verdana; height:100%;'>

          <!--next line black band doesn't go from top to bottom in edge/chrome - ok in firefox -->
          <td style='height:100%; text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;' rowspan='1'>15.5<br />The Road</td>
          <td style='margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px; width:1%; height:100%; background-color:black; border-top-color: 0; border-right-color: 0; border-bottom-color: 0; border-left-color: 0;' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
          <td style='width:121px;height:100%;' rowspan='1'> Poor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Great<br/>
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='1' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='2' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='3' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='4' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='5' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <br /> <br />
            <div style='text-align: center;'>
              <input onclick=window.open( 'RateSafety.aspx') type='button' style='width: 80px; padding:0' id='btnRateSafety' name='btnRateSafety' value='Rate Safety' visible='true' />
              <br/>
              <div style='width:110px'>&nbsp;
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </td>
    <td>
      The directions go here.
    </td>
    <td>
      Comments go here
    </td>
    <td>
      the number goes here
    </td>
    <td><br />&nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="MyRepeater:_ctl1:btnShowMap" value="Map" id="MyRepeater__ctl1_btnShowMap" style="width:35px; " />
      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        <span id="MyRepeater__ctl1_lFootnoteMap" style="font-weight:bold;">1</span></sup>
                    </a><br style="display:block;margin: 2px 0;" /><br style="display:block;margin: 1px 0;" />&nbsp;

      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        </sup>
                    </a><br style="display:block;margin: 2px 0;" /><br style="display:block;margin: 1px 0;" />&nbsp;

      <input type="submit" name="MyRepeater:_ctl3:btnShowWeather" value="Weather" id="MyRepeater__ctl3_btnShowWeather" style="width:60px;" />

      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        <span id="MyRepeater__ctl3_lFootnoteWeather" style="font-weight:bold;">1</span></sup>
                    </a><br /><br />

    </td>
    <td>
      http://www.aWebAddress.com
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: maybe avoiding tables and use display, else an awfull workaround for chrome: `td > table {position:absolute;transform:translatey(-50%)}
td {position:relative;}` which requires also a min-height and a min-width aside width:170px ....

Answer (score 0):

I added `padding: 0` and `height: 100px` to that table cell (the parent of the nested table) and that solved the problem (in Chrome). Actually, *any*  `height` setting in pixels works, even a smaller one. Apparently the 100% `height` percentage needs a reference.

```css
body (
margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style="font: 8pt Verdana; width:100%;">
  <tr style="background-color:#ffcc00;color:black;">
    <th style="width:170px">
      <table style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font: 8pt verdana; vertical-align: 100%; 
                        height: 100%; width:100%;">
        <tr>
          <td style="width:40%; margin:0px; text-align: left;">
            <strong>Mile<br />Marker</strong></td>
          <td style="width:1%;margin: 0px auto;">&nbsp;<br /></td>
          <td style="width:59%;margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;">
            <strong>The Safety<br />Rating</strong></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Directions</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Comments</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Number of Vehicles</strong>
    </th>
    <th style="padding: 9px; color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; 
                    font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;width:70px;">
      <strong>&nbsp;Map&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><br />
      <strong>&nbsp;Weather&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><br />
    </th>
    <th style="color: #000000; vertical-align: middle; font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt;">
      <strong>Source</strong>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr id="firstRow" style="background-color:#ffff99; font: 8pt verdana;height:100%">
    <!-- There will be multiple table rows added here - I just simplified the code to find out where 
                      my probem originated from -->
    <td style='height: 100px; padding:0; text-align:center;' rowspan='1'>
      <!--ok to here-->

      <!--In Edge and Chrome the nested table doesn't fill the entire <td> cell top to bottom - 
         Firefox works the way I would like it to -->
      <table id="This is where my problem resides" style='padding: 0px; margin: 0px; height: 100%; 
                        border:thin solid #800080; background-color:#ffff99;'>
        <tr style=' font: 8pt verdana; height:100%;'>

          <!--next line black band doesn't go from top to bottom in edge/chrome - ok in firefox -->
          <td style='height:100%; text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;' rowspan='1'>15.5<br />The Road</td>
          <td style='margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; padding: 0px; width:1%; height:100%; background-color:black; border-top-color: 0; border-right-color: 0; border-bottom-color: 0; border-left-color: 0;' rowspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>
          <td style='width:121px;height:100%;' rowspan='1'> Poor&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Great<br/>
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='1' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='2' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='3' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='4' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <input type='radio' name='rblSafety249' class='radio_b' value='5' runat='server' disabled="disabled" />
            <br /> <br />
            <div style='text-align: center;'>
              <input onclick=window.open( 'RateSafety.aspx') type='button' style='width: 80px; padding:0' id='btnRateSafety' name='btnRateSafety' value='Rate Safety' visible='true' />
              <br/>
              <div style='width:110px'>&nbsp;
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

    </td>
    <td>
      The directions go here.
    </td>
    <td>
      Comments go here
    </td>
    <td>
      the number goes here
    </td>
    <td><br />&nbsp;
      <input type="submit" name="MyRepeater:_ctl1:btnShowMap" value="Map" id="MyRepeater__ctl1_btnShowMap" style="width:35px; " />
      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        <span id="MyRepeater__ctl1_lFootnoteMap" style="font-weight:bold;">1</span></sup>
                    </a><br style="display:block;margin: 2px 0;" /><br style="display:block;margin: 1px 0;" />&nbsp;

      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        </sup>
                    </a><br style="display:block;margin: 2px 0;" /><br style="display:block;margin: 1px 0;" />&nbsp;

      <input type="submit" name="MyRepeater:_ctl3:btnShowWeather" value="Weather" id="MyRepeater__ctl3_btnShowWeather" style="width:60px;" />

      <a href='#footnote'><sup>
                        <span id="MyRepeater__ctl3_lFootnoteWeather" style="font-weight:bold;">1</span></sup>
                    </a><br /><br />

    </td>
    <td>
      http://www.aWebAddress.com
    </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Comment: Johannes you are right - this does fix it in Chrome and Edge BUT now Firefox looks like the others used to. At least this gives me a starting point to work at. Thank you so much for taking a look at this. I was pulling my hair out.

Comment: I am writing and viewing this in Firefox (Mac), and here in the snippet there is *no*  problem in Firefox, but it looks as desired....

Comment: Johannes - In the code where it says "Comment go here" change it to a long piece of text and you'll see the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Erica T. but unfortunately this didn't solve my problem.